# Where can I find a proper API reference?

Tags: python, scripting, documentation

I can't believe I have to ask this, but where do I find an actual API reference for Blender scripting? I just can't seem to find one. I see [*tutorials*](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/) but no proper reference documentation.

For instance, [this page](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.data.html) *feels* like it should be giving me a list of all the members of `bpy.data` but I don't see any way to get that information. The "next" button just takes me to the next section, and "modules" takes me somewhere else entirely.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** The linked dupe DOES NOT answer the question. Clearly you did not read my question. I can't find the ACTUAL API REFERENCE. I don't understand why this is so complex to answer.

How do I know what each "class" (or whatever the python equivalent is) member variable and function is?

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html ?

Comment: Or this one if you need "newest" https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/

Comment: And also writing a documentation is a huge job and not that necessary. Blender as an opensource project including all those function, it is hard to keep documentation good as other software like **Unity** or **Javascript**, they both make effort on their documentation.

Comment: @stphnl329 That's the same page I linked, only for 2.8. How do you actually find an API reference from there? As in.... I don't even know how to describe. Those pages are not API reference. Like.... for instance, with Unity I can see the Transform class. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html From there I can see every member variable and function available. How do I find that same sort of thing for Blender?

Comment: @Hikariztw See above ^ Also you have to be kidding about documentation not being that necessary. Documentation is exceedingly necessary. It's literally not possible to use an API without documentation.

Comment: @Clonex I haven't gone through and done scripting yet with Blender, but I'm under the impression that they've explained some basic functions/commands that they've built in, then the rest of the API are variable names that are meant to be self-explanatory as they directly correspond to various properties/buttons in Blender

Comment: @stphnl329 I'm sure the API names _are_ self-explanatory, but _WHAT ARE THEY?_ How do I know the member variables and functions? There MUST be documentation for this somewhere or no one could ever write any scripts!

Comment: In the _"for instance"_ 2.77 documentation link posted  above  you overlooked =====>    Type: [`bpy.types.BlendData`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData) <=====

Comment: Have you looked through this page? https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_api_reference.html# If you right-click on a property in Blender and select online manual, it'll redirect you to the website, and if you change the dashes to dots at the end of the redirect URL, that's the property name (ex. URL:  docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/scene_layout/object/properties/transforms.html#bpy-types-object-location  means the location property is bpy.types.object.location

Comment: Not every API is well explained in Blender Doc. By my experience, some function and structure is really missing. Which required coder to guess how to use them. Also, the python code have some tips in Blender Interactive console

Comment: @batFINGER Thank you! It seems like you were the only one to actually understand! It seems an odd way of laying out the docs, but hey, at least they're there. Thanks!

Comment: @batFINGER The question is open again. If you want to make your comment an answer I'll accept it :D

Comment: @Clonkex In case you didn't notice, you can click on the type field to see what's inside the classes, e.g. by clicking on `bpy.types.BlendData` on [this page](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.data.html) you see what attributes it stores. This applies to the entirety of the API docs and allows you to traverse the class hierarchies.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Thanks, yeah that's what batFINGER pointed out and what I had missed. Makes a lot more sense now but I still think it's an odd way of laying out the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Look for class members, (properties, methods *et al*), in the classes doc page.**

[`bpy.data`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.data.html) is  a reference to an instance of the [`bpy.types.BlendData`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData) class. All the members of that class will be found in the documentation page for the  class (or type),

Most python documentation, I am familiar with, is organized this way, and has often, as is the case here generated from the source.

There may be many references , in this example scrolling down to reference section see that [`context.blend_data`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.blend_data) is also  an instance of [`bpy.types.BlendData`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData).  Note Even though `context.blend_data` and `bpy.data` are both of the same type and for this case mostly the same object, but it is not necessarily so. *Might start using `me = context.blend_data.meshes.new(...)` for methods where `context` is passed.*

A type with numerous references is the  blender object. `bpy.types.Object` for instance the context object of any blender object type. The target of a driver, modifier, constraint on an object. A member of a collection: blend data objects; collection objects or scene objects  etc etc etc etc.

Blender uses the convention: names of properties and methods are in lower case, classes in title case. *eg* `bpy.types.WindowManager` is a class (being in `bpy.types` is a bit of a give away too), `bpy.context.window_manager` an instance of it.

Turn on [`developer extras`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/preferences/interface.html#prefs-interface-dev-extras) to get an API link by right clicking on a property.

Comment: Note; for some functions, right clicking and copying data path / looking up the API reference doesn't always give you the right path.